# Datatables sort date and datetime colums

Tags: jquery, datatables, momentjs

I have a page with several datatables. Some of the tables have just a date field by which it is sorted, and other tables on that same page have a datetime field. The locale for the date/datetime is German.

I can get Datatables to correctly sort by either date **OR** datetime but I cannot get it to sort by either. I created this fiddle with a single table:
https://jsfiddle.net/r23yfdz8/

```js
$.fn.dataTable.moment( 'DD.MM.YYYY' ); // uncomment this to sort column 1 correctly
    //$.fn.dataTable.moment( 'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm' ); // this sorts column 2 (date and time) correctly
    $('#example').DataTable()
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.19/sorting/datetime-moment.js"></script>
<table id="example">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>date</th>
                <th>date + time</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
<tr><td>20.01.2018</td><td>20.01.2018 09:00</td></tr>                 
<tr><td>12.02.2019</td><td>12.02.2019 16:00</td></tr>                 
<tr><td>13.06.2017</td><td>13.06.2017 09:00</td></tr>                 
<tr><td>20.01.2018</td><td>20.01.2018 16:00</td></tr>                 
<tr><td>01.10.2016</td><td>01.10.2016 09:00</td></tr>        
<tr><td>12.10.2018</td><td>12.10.2018 16:00</td></tr>                
<tr><td>21.10.2017</td><td>21.10.2017 09:00</td></tr>           
<tr><td>04.10.2018</td><td>04.10.2018 16:00</td></tr>            
<tr><td>13.10.2018</td><td>13.10.2018 09:00</td></tr>        
<tr><td>01.11.2018</td><td>01.11.2018 16:00</td></tr>        

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

1. Click on the second column header "date + time". You'll notice that it sorts the table correctly.
2. Click on the other column header "date". You'll notice that the date is all over the place and not sorting properly
3. In the JS code, comment out the second line, and uncomment the first line. After rerunning, the fiddle now sorts column 1 correctly, but fails sorting column 2.

I would love to add a classes ("sort-datetime" and "sort-date") in the DOM to the  tags which would then tell datatables how to sort the values but I am not knowledgeable enough to figure out how to do that.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$.fn.dataTable.moment` plug-in can be used multiple times in one table, to accommodate different formats.

If I un-comment both your formatters at the same time, then your demo works OK.

Comment: Oh my gosh you're right! Wow. I guess sometimes the most apparent solution is the best one haha

Comment: It's a nice plug-in. It makes use of DataTables' [built-in type detection](https://datatables.net/blog/2014-12-18#Automatic-type-detection-plug-in), behind the scenes, to check a column's data against each format. That's what lets it handle multiple formats (as long as the data in each column is consistent, of course). Then, moment.js does the rest.